# Ninja form fatal error how can i fix my website?

Tags: wordpress

Uncaught TypeError: Return value of NF_Admin_Metaboxes_Calculations::registerReactMetabox() must be an instance of void, none returned in /home2/r93682theg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/includes/Admin/Metaboxes/Calculations.php:37 Stack trace: #0 /home2/r93682theg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/includes/Admin/Metaboxes/Calculations.php(7): NF_Admin_Metaboxes_Calculations->registerReactMetabox() #1 /home2/r93682theg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/ninja-forms.php(370): NF_Admin_Metaboxes_Calculations->__construct() #2 /home2/r93682theg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/ninja-forms.php(1223): Ninja_Forms::instance() #3 /home2/r93682theg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/ninja-forms.php(1226): Ninja_Forms() #4 /home2/r93682theg/public_html/wp-settings.php(409): include_once('/home2/r93682th...') #5 /home2/r93682theg/public_html/wp-config.php(96): require_once('/home2/r93682th...') #6 /home2/r93682theg/public_html/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home2/r93682th in /home2/r93682theg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/includes/Admin/Metaboxes/Calculations.php on line 37
There has been a critical error on this website.

HELP!!! How can i recover my website ?

Comment: offtopic here, should be moved to wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: see https://wordpress.org/support/topic/3-6-5-not-working/

Answer (score 3):

your PHP version is outdated and recent versions of Ninja Forms are no longer compatible with old PHPs (7.0 and around).

1. **Long term answer** : update your PHP to 7.4 or more
2. **Short term answer** : to recover your website quickly, you may remove the type checking on the file mentioned in the error file : public_html/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/includes/Admin/Metaboxes/Calculations.php.
   On line 37, remove `:void`
   This is ugly and will break again on next update of this file, but it may give you time to fix your PHP

Comment: Older versions like the [ones discussed on the official plugin page](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/3-6-5-not-working/) still don't work 100% with PHP 7.0. No more fatal error on install, but viewing submissions will fail with a server error.